# $M$ numbered balls (1 to $M$) drawn from urn (without replacement) - probability that at least one ball number matches its pick number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There is an urn with $M$ numbered balls ($1$ to $M$). All balls are drawn without replacement. Find the probability that at least one ball number matches its pick number.

I tried to find the probability that no ball number matches its pick number and then subtract it from $1$, but couldn't manage to find that either.

Comment: To find the probability no ball number matches, divide the number $D_M$ of derangements of the set $\{1,2,\dots, M\}$ by $M!$. For derangements, please see Wikipedia. There will not be a closed form, but still the answer will look very nice.

Comment: You are welcome. You are likely to bump into ideas connected with derangements again. There are a quite a lot of answers about derangements on MSE, but I think the Wikipedia article is quite thorough, and worth knowing about.